# XML import to ArcGIS gdb

Tags: arcgis-desktop, xml, file-geodatabase, inspire

i am trying to create datasets from xmd files (based on INSPIRE data model). i get a notice that my "workspace does not found"). does anyone have experience with that?

i am looking for a schema for base mapping and topographic mapping that baset on iso19101 data model or allike. will be thankfull for any help.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your Question to include details about the version of ArcGIS for Desktop that you are using, and the precise steps you performed to see this error appear, please?

Comment: Do you mean XML ? what is XMD ?

Comment: i am using 10.1 ver. trying to import from arccatalog.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some link to download schemas. you need to import them to an empty GDB with ArcCatalog (right click on the GDB and the Import XML)

http://www.isotc211.org/schemas/2005/gmd/

http://standards.iso.org/ittf/licence.html

Comment: i am getting this note: "unable to find xml element"

Comment: I don't think these XMls containing empty data sets, only mata data configurations